# how to change the value of a variable in pyqt6?

Tags: python

I am creating a pizza ordering app for a school assessment. I have some code for the checkout but if i don't select a drink or one of the pizzas, it will still charge you for it. i tried something here but this is what it says.

```
DrPrice = (DrPrice1)
NameError: name 'DrPrice1' is not defined
```

here is the code:

```
def AddDrink():
    if DrinkUI.CokeCheck.isChecked():
        CheckoutUI.DrinkOrder.setText("Coke Classic")
        CheckoutUI.DrinkPrice.setText("5")
        def DrPrice1():
            DrPrice = int(5)
        

    elif DrinkUI.CokeZCheck.isChecked():
        CheckoutUI.DrinkOrder.setText("Coke Zero")
        CheckoutUI.DrinkPrice.setText("5")
        def DrPrice1():
            DrPrice = int(5)
        

    elif DrinkUI.FantaCheck.isChecked():
        CheckoutUI.DrinkOrder.setText("Fanta")
        CheckoutUI.DrinkPrice.setText("5")
        def DrPrice1():
            DrPrice = int(5)
        

    elif DrinkUI.AJCheck.isChecked():
        CheckoutUI.DrinkOrder.setText("Apple Juice")
        CheckoutUI.DrinkPrice.setText("5")
        def DrPrice1():
            DrPrice = int(5)
        

    elif DrinkUI.WaterCheck.isChecked():
        CheckoutUI.DrinkOrder.setText("Water")
        CheckoutUI.DrinkPrice.setText("5")
        def DrPrice1():
            DrPrice = int(5)

       
        

DrPrice = (DrPrice1)
PizzaPrice1 = int(10)
PizzaPrice2 = int(10)
DroneFee = int(5)
ItemTotalPr = PizzaPrice1 + PizzaPrice2 + DrPrice
Total = PizzaPrice1 + PizzaPrice2 + DroneFee + DrPrice
```

this is just the code for the drinks but i don't get why it says DrPrice1 is not defined when i clearly have. please help.

Comment: It is defined locally in a function but not on module level ("globally").

Comment: The error is clear. You didn't define it. The keyword is "scope of a variable". There are tones of tutorials such as [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp). Do a preliminary research and debugging at first. See [ask].

Comment: Just going to point out, `int(5)` is the same as saying `5`. So there is no need for the cast.
Also, the only thing you change is `CheckoutUI.DrinkOrder.setText`, so everything else can be put outside of the if-elif blocks.